# How to pipe requests into clean-css in nodejs?

Tags: css, node.js, request, minify, clean-css

I'm trying to pipe request output into clean-css to minify and then provide it as a response. The example app in question is built on restify.

Sample Objective Code :

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/css/style.css";
request.get(url).pipe(minify()).pipe(res);
```

How can I define the minify() function to accept stream and return one. I've tried dozens of packages, none worked.
Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm trying to set up a running mini-app with your code. Where does _request_ come from? It it https://github.com/request/request?

Comment: @PatrickHund Yes, its from that request package.

Comment: The application is setup as kind of a reverse proxy server, albeit customized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Transform stream. It gets the CSS code from the stream created by `request.get`, does the minification magic and returns the minified CSS.

Here's a working example:

```
const restify = require('restify');
const request = require('request');
const { Transform } = require('stream');
const CleanCSS = require('clean-css');

const server = restify.createServer();
const cleanCss = new CleanCSS();
const url = 'http://www.example.com/css/style.css';

function createMinifyTransform() {
    return new Transform({
        transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
            const output = cleanCss.minify(chunk.toString());
            this.push(output.styles);
            callback();
        }
    });
}

function respond(req, res) {
    request
        .get(url)
        .pipe(createMinifyTransform())
        .pipe(res);
}

server.get('/', respond);

server.listen(8080, () => console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url));
```

Comment: One issue that I faced with above code is subsequent requests for same file turn up empty HTTP 200 response. Am trying to see what could be the issue, also would it be better to process the entire file at once, giving better chance at compression ?

Comment: Whoopsie, fixed the code example. You have to create a new minify transform with every request.

Comment: Works beautifully!